# Why css of ngx-datatable is broken after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

There is a problem about css of @swimlane/ngx-datatable. I used dt but when i try to reload the page, css of the page is broken. I do not understand why. At initial there is no problem, changing page there is no problem, but reloading is a problematic. Im sharing ss and code part. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Here is the [ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q50X.png)

Here is the codepart =>

```
<ngx-datatable style="width: 90%" id="ngx-dt1"
     class="material whitespace-nowrap single-selection pt-5"
     [rows]="rows"
     [columnMode]="columnMode.force"
     [headerHeight]="60"
     rowHeight="50">
     <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let col of columns" [name]="col.name.toUpperCase()">
     </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: Can you add ss of broken css? also add the typescript code.

Comment: i think it is about with css thats why im sayin broken css. you can reach my github repo ill give you a link. I find a way but it is temporary solution. https://github.com/androloper/web/tree/main/web-monitoring/src/app/modules/datatable3